# Is there any way to get blender control rig in unreal engine.?

Tags: animation, rigging, export, constraints, unreal-engine

I need to use control rig for a model that was created in blender and rigged with bones and control rigs. I need the same control rig instead of creating it from scratch in unreal. Is it possible to use blender control rig in unreal engine instead of using direct bone adjustments?. If it is possible, what are the model/blender export settings I need to follow!.